# Binance API error on quantity within range

Tags: binance

Getting error, on Binance test API. SPOT TRADING

Symbol: BNBUSDT

Quantity: 0.331

```
Responce:
{"code":-1013,"msg":"Filter failure: LOT_SIZE"}
```

On testing on
Quantity: 0.33

```
ORDER IS EXECUTED
```

On checking the LOT_SIZE

```
        "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
        "minQty": "0.01000000",
        "maxQty": "9000.00000000",
        "stepSize": "0.01000000"
```

Can you please tell what error is causing the ERROR -1013, As the value 0.331 is within range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 0.331 is within `minQty` and `maxQty`, but it does not respect the `stepSize` of `0.01000000`.  In other words you need  to round your value to 2 decimal places.